# SD card reader not working in multi card reader

Tags: usb, mount, sd-card

I've got a multicard reader in my machine.  It lists itself as

> Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0151 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Mass Storage Device (Multicard Reader)

It mounts CF cards just fine, and initially mounted SD cards as well.  More recently, it stopped mounting SD cards.  I assumed this to be a hardware failure and used a dedicated USB SD card reader.  I've just got a new USB multi-card reader for something else and tried it against my machine out of curiosity.  It describes itself as

> Bus 003 Device 004: ID 048d:1336 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. SD/MMC Cardreader

It does exactly the same thing, CF cards work fine, SD cards don't register at all.  This makes me suspect that the problem with the first device is actually software and not hardware.  The machine is currently on 13.10, the problem was the same on 13.04.

Any suggestions